# The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, authentication, kerberos, certificate

some time ago I installed SQL server 2016 developer edition on a windows 10 home edition environment (*a laptop to be precise*) and everything was fine.

then someone - an administrator on the box - decided without telling me, to rename said box.

after that when attempting connection to SQL server we have been experiencing the following error messages:

[image]

[image]

this is a very similar question to this one:

[“The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted” when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn)

I have been also here:

[The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2d4d6a0f-de2c-4dc3-b813-46167f3ade0c/the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-cannot-generate-sspi-context-microsoft-sql-server-error?forum=sqlsecurity)

and I have been using the Kerberos Configuration Manager, which gives me a different error message

[image]

I should say that *I Am able to connect to this instance of SQL server by SQL server authentication* but I want to connect using windows authentication.

just to be clear - this is all a local machine, that does not belong to any domain.

I am not quite sure as how to proceed from here, what I want is to use windows authentication.

The error message related to certificates makes me think about re-issuing certificates here.
I am not sure as for how to get this done, or if this is a valid way to go about this situation.

I will not be around this machine for the day, but I will catch up as soon as possible. I will carry on with my research when time permits.

Comment: Have you run sp_dropserver, sp_addserver to ensure that the internal SQL name is correct (ie is @@servername different than the machine name?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On connection pop up click on options
[image]

Then make sure the "Trust server certificate" is checked

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that this is a WORKAROUND, not a proper solution. The true solution is to deal with the certificate trust issue.

Answer (score 6):

go advanced "options" and put TrustServerCertificate=True to Additional Connection Parameters

Comment: How and why does this solve the problem?

Comment: it says the client that it can trust the untrusted certificate for the encrypted connection to the server. its untrusted because the root certificate is not installed on the clients machine